# why does the second link click redirect to partial not dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an edit partial view to load in a dialog, which works the first time it's called, the edit then saves the data, great.

However if you don't refresh the page, which I don't want to have to do, and click 'edit' again, you are redirected to the partial page I am trying to load.

It looks like the AJAX is being ignored and the Action method in the controller is being called instead.

I have unobtrusive added through the bundles in my layout page, which the main view uses, the partial doesn't, but I don't believe it needs to.

I have also tried using `preventDefault` and different approached of `return false;` with no success, like the below:

```
editBtn.click(function (e) {
            editDialogPlaceholder.load(this.href, function () {
                e.preventDefault(); //tried
                $(this).dialog('open');
                return false; //tried
            })
        return false;
    });
```

How can I stop this?

**AJAX/JS**

```
$(function () {
        var editBtn = $('.editLink');
        var editDialogPlaceholder = $('#editDialogUI');

        editBtn.button();
        // build the dialog form
        editDialogPlaceholder.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load('@Url.Action("Edit","Announcements")');
            },
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    saveAnnouncement();
                    fetchList();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        // on click load the dialog form, return false to stop redirect
        editBtn.click(function () {
            editDialogPlaceholder.load(this.href, function () {
                $(this).dialog('open');
            })
            return false;
        });
    });
    //post data back to the controller to save to the db
    function saveAnnouncement() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Edit","Announcements")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('form').serialize()
            })
        }

        function fetchList() {
            var aList = $('#announcementList');
            aList.load('@Url.Action("Fetch")');
        }
```

**Edit action method**

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
                var announcementModel = (from a in db.DbAnnouncement
                           where a.Id == id
                           select a).SingleOrDefault();
                return PartialView("Edit", announcementModel);
        }
```

**Html.ActionLinks being used to open the dialog** - second time of clicking it redirects to the partial specified in the controller.

```
<div class="announcementTableCell">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model[i].Id }, new { @class = "editLink" })

                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { Model[i].Id }, new { @class = "dltLink" })
                </div>
```

Comment: After you do the first AJAX call is the `.editLink` element replaced with a new copy?

Comment: Ah, that could be it, that's the other thing I need to get the partial holding all the items in the list (where the editLink class btns are) to refresh through without full page reload - was going to sort that after. I attempted to do it with my fetchList() function.

Comment: Then you'll need to bind the click event to a static parent. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: If I get the partial refresh working I won't need to bind it to a static element though, right?

Comment: As long as you never replace the original link. But if you use a delegate like in that answer it's really not much more code.

Comment: OK - thank you - quick try didn't work using `.on` - `editBtn.on("click", editBtn, function () {
            editDialogPlaceholder.load(this.href, function () {
                $(this).dialog('open');
            })
            return false;
        });`

Comment: You're button click event is only getting called once. You're `@html.ActionLink("Edit")` is what is getting fired off the second time...

Comment: it should be `$(document).on('click', '.editBtn', fuction(){ //..load stuff..// });` where `$(document)` could be any static parent element to `.editBtn`.

Comment: You are still binding to the dynamic target `editBtn.on()`. It would be `$("parent_selector").on("click", ".editLink", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }`

Comment: Okay - thank you both for your help and explanations. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as proposed in comments was to use `jQuery.fn.on` for the click button as the page wasn't being refreshed at the time, so binding to a static element that wasn't being refreshed meant that the action method was being called and as such redirecting to the partial view.

Therefore the working button click code:

```
$('#announcementList').on("click", ".editLink", function () {
            editDialogPlaceholder.load(this.href, function () {
                $(this).dialog('open');
            })
            return false;
        });
```